# Could not autowire field: private

Tags: java, spring

I have seen the same question in SO but coudn't figure what's going on with my configuration.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.mmm.service.ReadPropertyFilesTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mmm.singletons.VersionHandler com.mmm.service.ReadPropertyFilesTest.vHandler; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.mmm.singletons.VersionHandler] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:384)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:331)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:213)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:292)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

This is the test class I use.

```
package com.mmm.service;    

    @Configurable
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "classpath*:spring/applicationContext.xml",
    "classpath*:spring/applicationContext-jpa.xml",
    "classpath*:spring/applicationContext-security.xml" })
    public class ReadPropertyFilesTest {

        @Autowired
        private VersionHandler vHandler;


        @Test
        public void readPropertyFilestest() {
            //VersionHandler vc = new Versi
            System.out.println("open mapping \t"+vHandler.isIS_OPEN_MAPPING());
        }

    }
```

VersionHandler class

```
package com.mmm.singletons;

    @Service
    @Configurable
    public class VersionHandler {

        @Value(value = "${IS_OPEN_MAPPING}")
        private boolean IS_OPEN_MAPPING;

        public boolean isIS_OPEN_MAPPING() {
            return IS_OPEN_MAPPING;
        }

        public void setIS_OPEN_MAPPING(boolean iS_OPEN_MAPPING) {
            IS_OPEN_MAPPING = iS_OPEN_MAPPING;
        }
    }
```

applicationcontext xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd         
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd         
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">


    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties" />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <context:spring-configured />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mmm">
        <context:include-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*"
            type="regex" />
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
            type="annotation" />
        <context:include-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Component" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


    <!-- Logging Aspect Bean Definition -->
    <bean id="logAspect" class="com.mmm.aspect.LoggingAspect" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect"
        factory-method="aspectOf">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Can somebody give me advise how to fix this?

**Update** 
webmvc-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties" />

    <!-- The controllers are autodetected POJOs labeled with the @Controller 
        annotation. -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mmm.webapi.controllers"
        use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
            type="annotation" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <!-- Turns on support for mapping requests to Spring MVC @Controller methods 
        Also registers default Formatters and Validators for use across all @Controllers -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="applicationConversionService">
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper" ref="applicationObjectMapper" />
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
    <bean id="applicationObjectMapper" class="com.mmm.webapi.conversion.ApplicationObjectMapper" />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources -->
    <mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/"
        mapping="/resources/**" />

    <!-- Allows for mapping the DispatcherServlet to "/" by forwarding static 
        resource requests to the container's default Servlet -->
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <!-- Register "global" interceptor beans to apply to all registered HandlerMappings -->
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor" />
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
            p:paramName="lang" />
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <!-- Selects a static view for rendering without the need for an explicit 
        controller -->
    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index" />
    <mvc:view-controller path="/uncaughtException" />
    <mvc:view-controller path="/resourceNotFound" />
    <mvc:view-controller path="/dataAccessFailure" />

    <!-- Resolves localized messages*.properties and application.properties 
        files in the application to allow for internationalization. The messages*.properties 
        files translate Roo generated messages which are part of the admin interface, 
        the application.properties resource bundle localizes all application specific 
        messages such as entity names and menu items. -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
        id="messageSource" p:basenames="WEB-INF/i18n/messages,WEB-INF/i18n/application"
        p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false" />

    <!-- Store preferred language configuration in a cookie -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver"
        id="localeResolver" p:cookieName="locale" />

    <!-- Resolves localized <theme_name>.properties files in the classpath to 
        allow for theme support -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource"
        id="themeSource" />

    <!-- Store preferred theme configuration in a cookie -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver"
        id="themeResolver" p:cookieName="theme" p:defaultThemeName="standard" />

    <!-- This bean resolves specific types of exceptions to corresponding logical 
        - view names for error views. The default behaviour of DispatcherServlet 
        - is to propagate all exceptions to the servlet container: this will happen 
        - here with all other types of exceptions. -->
<!--    <bean -->
<!--        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver" -->
<!--        p:defaultErrorView="uncaughtException"> -->
<!--        <property name="exceptionMappings"> -->
<!--            <props> -->
<!--                <prop key=".DataAccessException">dataAccessFailure</prop> -->
<!--                <prop key=".NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException">resourceNotFound</prop> -->
<!--                <prop key=".TypeMismatchException">resourceNotFound</prop> -->
<!--                <prop key=".MissingServletRequestParameterException">resourceNotFound</prop> -->
<!--            </props> -->
<!--        </property> -->
<!--    </bean> -->

    <!-- Enable this for integration of file upload functionality -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"
        id="multipartResolver" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver"
        id="tilesViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer"
        id="tilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml</value>
                <!-- Scan views directory for Tiles configurations -->
                <value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean
        class="com.mmm.webapi.conversion.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean"
        id="applicationConversionService" />

    <!-- <bean class="com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.SpringSwaggerConfig" 
        /> 
    -->
    <bean class="com.mmm.webapi.documentation.SwaggerConfig" />

</beans>
```

Comment: please add the `package` declaration to your classes

Comment: Make all variables public ?

Comment: For whatever reason, the class `ValidHandler` is not discovered by Spring. Does your application starts? Does it fail only in unit tests?

Comment: `<context:component-scan base-package="com.mmm">` is not fetching your `@Service` class. You specify to check only for `@Component`

Comment: @ByeBye `@Service`, `@Repository`, `@Controller` all extend `@Component`

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle right. Still probably configuration is wrong. The include filter is missing and class is not registered

Comment: I tried with @component as well. that didn't work.

Comment: `<context:include-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*"  type="regex" />` what about that?

Comment: @Configurable by default is autowirable? Had a look an the definition and it says no.

Comment: Can you try to add an `include-filter` with the exact fully qualified class name? `<context:include-filter expression="com.mmm.singletons.VersionHandler" type="regex" />` ?

Comment: @ByeBye it is to ensures that Spring doesn't spend time introspecting Roo-specific ITD aspects. I have been removing Roo configuration from this applicaiton. I tried commenting that code but I am still with the issue.

Comment: `<context:component-scan base-package="com.mmm">` change to `<context:component-scan base-package="com.mmm.*">`

Comment: I tried both your hints. Still no luck. thanks Byebye and @Aranud Denoyelle

Comment: @newday Can you start your application or does it only fail only when trying to execute unit tests?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I know nothing about this annotation, but it has a property autowire and default value is no, should we change to by type?

Comment: Are you sure `applicationcontext xml` in `spring/` folder under `test` folder ?

Comment: I have other test classes which are works totally fine. This is a new test class I added after removing Spring-Roo from the project.